# Bluetooth Low Energy cached? How to work around it

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I experience an unpleasant problem for which I can't really find a conclusive reason: if I reprogram my BLE112 module (BLEBee from Michael Kroll / seeedstudio), for some reason the settings (especially the UUID keys to peripherals) are not being updated.
This is very unpleasant since that almost makes it impossible to connect to the device via iOS / Xcode.

Any leads on how to solve this and what would cause this issue?

Note: I reprogram them using CC Debugger and BLEUpdate from Bluegiga. I'm sure the values are in fact being reprogrammed, but iOS seems to keep the old info at least for some time.

(iOS 8 / Xcode 6 beta)

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574805/iphone-how-to-erase-wipe-out-bluetooth-4-0-data

Comment: How are you accessing it using core bluetooth? Can you post any of your peripheral delegate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to reset the settings of your phone? This is a common problem with iOS. Once you connected to the e.g. original firmware of the BLEBee and change the services and characteristics, iOS will show you the cached ones. Try to initially turn off Bluetooth, kill you app, restart BT and start your app again.
If this does not help Reset the Settings of your Phone.

Hope this helps,
Michael.

Comment: that works well indeed. I'm still seeing differences in how iOS 8 does it from iOS 7 though. Interesting. Will try to debug some more and get my fingers behind the exact reasons. Hard to do though if you have a school job and can't focus on it for more than a few hours.